# Too many AppEngine Datastore reads from GWT client

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, gwt-rpc

I have a problem related to Google AppEngine datastore and a GWT client.

I have started from a template project "Android Connected AppEngine " in Eclipse ( using GPE) and advanced by implementing this ( http://code.google.com/p/cloud-tasks-io/ ) project presented at Google I/O 2011 ( http://bradabrams.com/2011/05/google-io-session-overview-android-app-engine-a-developers-dream-combination/ ).

After implementing the project, I deployed the application on AppEngine and my Android device.

The problem is the number of datastore reads from the GWT client is very large ( 1/second). What can I do about this? My source code for the GWT client is exactly like the one from the CloudTasksIO project from above.

Bellow are the 2 screenshots from the Dashboard of the application and from the Logs. All the requests came from my browser.

Thanks.

[image: My logs]

[image: Dashboard]

Answer (score 1):

[`This`](http://code.google.com/p/cloud-tasks-io/source/browse/trunk/CloudTasks-AppEngine/src/com/cloudtasks/client/CloudTasksWidget.java#296) is a Scheduler that calls a method that is querying the datastore and is set to repeat every `DELAY_MS`, which is set to 1000 [`here`](http://code.google.com/p/cloud-tasks-io/source/browse/trunk/CloudTasks-AppEngine/src/com/cloudtasks/client/CloudTasksWidget.java#214).

You could increase the polling time to reduce datastore reads if you are just following the example. For a real project you probably would want to have the user manually request updates, open a channel, or use some sort of comet solution that allows you to push the updates to the client.